# Many Page views counter with a @Singleton

Tags: design-patterns, jakarta-ee, singleton, ejb, counter

AFAIK @Singleton EJB is suited to count page views, with something like:

```
@Singleton
public class CounterBean {
    private int hits = 1;

    // Increment and return the number of hits
    public int getHits() {
        return hits++;
    }
}
```

That works fine for a web application of one page, What if the web app has let's say 1K pages, and we want to show the counter for each view each time it's loaded.

Would a @Singleton be appropriated for this? I mean, Would this be **efficient**? (Having *many* beans to update frequently a single instance)

My guess a single instance to manage all the web pages counter is not efficient. Imagine thousands of @RequestScoped beans updating a `Map <ViewID, Count>` in a @Singleton, will lead to heavy concurrency...

For updating persisting values on redeployments, I was thinking in using `@PostConstruct` (pull from database), `@PreDestroy` (push to database) annotations.

Page view counter is to be shown in each view.

The number of web pages is dynamic.

I understand that Google Analytics does this job, but the question is how to make this in Java EE.

App Server: Jboss 7.1

Comment: It will help to know which application server you are using, some of them collect statistics

Comment: Still, I would like to know both solutions. (Server & Singleton)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to implement a page view counter, you'd better make it persistent, else the counts will restart from 0 at each redeploy or restart of the application. And the numbers won't be right if the application is clustered on several servers.

If it's just an exercise, the you should use [bean-managed concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html#giptu), and use an `ConcurrentHashMap` containing instances of `AtomicInteger`. See the documentation of these two classes to understand how they work, especially the documentation for `putIfAbsent()` (unless you know all the pages in adavance and can prepopulate the map with counters set to 0, in which case you won't even need to use `putIfAbsent()`).

Comment: PostConstruct is called after bean construction. I guess you meant PreDestroy. I still wouldn't do that. First because if the container can't stop correctly, you would lose all the temporary data. Second, because threre are ready-made solutions for this problem, such as Google-Analytics, which do that better, and provide much more functionality.

Comment: Yes, Sorry. OK. How would you pull from Google Analytics the number of visits and get them displayed? And Please comment about this singleton strategy/pattern efficiency for counting views.

Comment: See http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9303/how-do-i-show-visitor-count-in-my-page. With a correct non-blocking algorithm based on a concurrent hashmap and an AtomicInteger or AtomicLong, I think you'll have something really fast. Much faster than the IO needed to go to the database. But it's not reliable enough: keeping numbers in memory for days or months is dangerous.

Comment: Maybe the non-blocking algorithm can be combined with a timer to persist it, every i.e. 1 hour. What do you think?